# Windows batch file copying/renaming files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been working on creating a batch file which moves files from one dir to another dir and if the filename already exists rename it then move it over.

I'm really new to creating batch files so heres what I have so far

```
set temp=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\a\a1
set dir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\a\
set /a "counter=0"
set "duplicate=-copy^("
set "bracket=^)"

if exist "%temp%" ( ^
for %%i in (%temp%\*) ^
do ^
if exist "%dir%\%%~ni%%~xi" ( call :checkFileName %%~ni %%~xi) ^
ELSE ( move %temp%\%%~ni%%~xi %dir% ) )^
ELSE ( echo doesnt exist)

:checkFileName
echo test
set fileName=%1
set fileExtenstion=%2
set /a "counter+=1
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
if exist %dir%%fileName%%duplicate%%counter%%bracket%%fileExtenstion% ( IF defined %1 (
IF defined %2 (call :checkFileName %1 %2 )) ) ELSE (ren %temp%\%fileName%%fileExtenstion%  %fileName%%duplicate%%counter%%bracket%%fileExtenstion% )
timeout 30
goto :eof
:increment
set /a "counter+=1"
goto :eof
```

I've no idea to increment a var before calling my checkFileName function. I think recursively calling the same function is the right idea but I'm a bit rusty with the commands/syntax as I only started this on friday.

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated. (If you know any useful links/books that are worth a look let me know!)

timeout 600

Comment: Are you processing single folders or folder trees?  Does it matter what kind of renaming is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "tempdir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\a\a1"
set "dir=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\a"
set "tempdir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
set "dir=U:\destdir"
set "duplicate=-copy("
set "bracket=)"

if exist "%tempdir%" (
 for %%i in ("%tempdir%\*") do (
  if exist "%dir%\%%~nxi" ( call :checkFileName "%%~ni" "%%~xi"
  ) ELSE ( 
   move "%tempdir%\%%~nxi" "%dir%" >nul
  ) 
 )
) ELSE ( 
 echo doesnt EXIST
)

GOTO :eof

:checkFileName
set "fileName=%~1"
set "fileExtenstion=%~2"
set /a counter=0
:nexttry
set /a counter+=1
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
if exist "%dir%\%fileName%%duplicate%%counter%%bracket%%fileExtenstion%" GOTO nexttry
move "%tempdir%\%fileName%%fileExtenstion%" "%dir%\%fileName%%duplicate%%counter%%bracket%%fileExtenstion%"  >nul
goto :eof
```

Here's a revised version. I'll explain the changes I've made:

**@echo off** turns off command-echoing

**setlocal** ensures any changes made to the environment are backed-out when the procedure ends.

I've added to extra `sets` to re-set the directories to suit *my* system. You'd need to delete these two lines for yours.

**temp** is a special name which points to a temporary directory. One of quite a few. Best not to use that particular name - replaced with `tempdir`

**set** when used for a numeric set doesn't require quotes. In a string-set, the syntax `set "var=value"` is used to ensure that trailing spaces on the command-line are not included into the value assigned (which can cause chaos - spaces are sort of - invisible.) Note that in a string `set`, spaces on **both** sides of the `=` are significant...

I prefer to assign directorynames into variables without the trailing `\`. This allows the value to be extended with the least gymnastics. Personal preference - but you used it both ways...

The carets are **not** required before `(` and are only required before `)` where the *syntax* would close an open parenthesis (ie. in a parenthesised statement-sequence as may occur in an `if`, `else` or `do`.) Used arbitrarily, this can lead to stray literal carets in filenames, for instance.

**carets at end-of-line** is a valid but easily-lost and a little-used technique. The rule for breaking statements over multiple lines is crudely, keep `do`, `if` or `else` on the same physical line as its `(` and `else` on the same physical line as the closing-parenthesis that precedes it. Then no eol-caret is required.

Batch simply charges on through statements. It has no concept of the `end of a procedure` and needs to be told when the procedure ends. This can be done with a `goto :eof` statement (which jumps to the physical end-of-file) or an `exit /b` statement (which returns from a subroutine, optionally setting `errorlevel`. `goto :eof` effectively does the smae thing in most circumstances and is way more common.)

**%%~nxi** means the name-and-extension of the file `%%i`. Of course, it's quite legal to use `%%~ni` and its counterpart individually, but it's not necessary. Note however that these parts should be despatched in `"quotes"` to the subroutine because each part *may* contain spaces. `"quotes"`make a spaces-containing-string appear as one string with spaces rather than a series of strings.

**>nul** redirects the `move` command's report "1 file(s) moved" to the bit-bucket.

Setting the two variables within `checkfilename` should be done after removing the quotes applied in the `call` - that's the purpose of the `~` before the parameter-number.

`counter` can be set to zero, then incremented.

If the proposed new filename exists, then simply increment the number and try again until you hit a name that doesn't exist. Yes - `counter` will run out eventually. It tops out at 2**31-1. Might take a while...

Note the use of `quotes` in the `if exist` and `move`. This is to guard against spaces in file/directorynames. The same goes for the `for %%i in ("%tempdir%\*")` used earlier...you may notice that in my testing, I used (deliberately) a directoryname that contained spaces. As it happens, the filenames I used also had spaces in them.

One last warning - There is no doubt that some odd filenames may choke on these procedures, but they should be few and far between. Filenames containing carets may be a problem, for instance.

Welcome to batch!

Comment: Thanks alot! I'm glad you explained your changes ( it would have taken me a while to figure it all out).

Comment: +1 nice explanation of the details.  Not sure if I actually learned anything new after [some number of] years, but it was very well explained and valuable for new coders. Didn't read like a manual but more as advice.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a learning project, I recommend you study the XCOPY command.